# Using an introduced member?

Tags: c#-4.0, postsharp

I've been reading up on PostSharp, and I want to use introduction to inject a member. For a stupid example, say I write an aspect that introduces

```
public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Easy enough, if i disassemble, I see its there. Now the tricky part.. within the same class, I'd like to do something like;

```
public void PrintGuid()
{
     Console.WriteLine(this.Id);
}
```

How would I do this? Alternately, if that doesn't work, can I do something like declare the variable in the class, and then use it in the aspect? So the class would have

```
public Guid Id;
```

And the aspect would do something like

```
this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this at design time?

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to do it here

- http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-14-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-1.aspx
- http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-15-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-2.aspx

If you need to use it at design time then you probably shouldn't be introducing it at compile time. Either change it to be there at design time or you can abstract an interface and use Post.Cast<>() to take advantage of it

```
var MyClass = Post.Cast<IMyInterface>(...);

MyClass.MyIntroducedMember = 10;
```